# Flask-WTForms can't find WTForms in my project directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, wtforms

This is my first post on StackOverflow so Hello everyone.

I'm doing blog application to learn Python and Flask and I would like to launch it on Google App Engine. Unfortunately I have small problem with importing WTForms to the application. I'm currently using Flask 0.9, WTForms 1.0.1 and Flask-WTForms 0.8. I've added flaskext_wtf folder to root path of my project but I'm getting error from html5.py file.

```
File "/Users/lucas/Workspace/blog/flask_wtf/html5.py", line 1, in <module>
from wtforms import TextField
File "/Users/lucas/Workspace/blog/flask/exthook.py", line 86, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf.wtforms
```

It looks like it tries to find wtforms inside the extension path instead of my project path. How can I inform the html5.py file to look for the wtforms in the root?

Here are sources of my project - https://bitbucket.org/lucas_mendelowski/wblog/src

Comment: Hi Lucas, you really should look into using a VirtualEnv your Python projects. Check out this free online book for a complete guide on a good Flask project structure: [http://exploreflask.com](http://exploreflask.com)

Answer (score 6):

I think your Virtualenv does not have the Flask-WTF module.
Write the following command in your command line under virtualenv

```
pip install Flask-WTF
```

or you may do this, but it is not recommended.

```
easy_install Flask-WTF
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, I finally manage with this issue (but I'm not sure if it's the right way).

Change imports in these files:

1) flaskwtf/init_.py

From:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import html5
from flask.ext.wtf.form import Form
from flask.ext.wtf import recaptcha

from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha.fields import RecaptchaField
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha.widgets import RecaptchaWidget
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha.validators import Recaptcha
```

To:

```
import html5
from form import Form
import recaptcha

from recaptcha.fields import RecaptchaField
from recaptcha.widgets import RecaptchaWidget
from recaptcha.validators import Recaptcha
```

2) flaskwtf/recaptcha/init_.py:

From:

```
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha import fields
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha import  validators 
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha import  widgets
```

To:

```
import fields
import validators 
import widgets
```

I've also posted a solution on github - https://github.com/rduplain/flask-wtf/issues/46#issuecomment-7376577

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect import. You are probably doing:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import wtforms
```

There is no such module.
Instead you should do:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField
```

If you want HTML5 widgets, just use the following. For example, you can import URLField as

```
from flask.ext.wtf.html5 import URLField
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but please check the code before answering on question. In my application file I've got:    from flask.ext.wtf import Form (which is correct, I think). But in html5.py file in the Flask-WTForms there is: from wtforms import TextField which is mapped to: flask.ext.wtf.wtforms.

Comment: I think you should just use Flask-WTF and not WTForms standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong. Also, make sure you install Flask-WTF which automatically installs WTForm.

As far as importing fields goes, according to the docs..

```
From version 0.9.0, Flask-WTF will not import anything from wtforms 
you need to import fields from wtforms.


    from flask_wtf import Form
    from wtforms import TextField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

    class MyForm(Form):
        name = TextField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Please review the [Flask-WTF quick start guide](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html).